# Need Assistance with a regex pattern in Python – Parsing complex HTML structures

Tags: python, regex, parsing, web-scraping, html-parsing

I'm trying to parse complex HTML structures using Python's re module, and I've run into a roadblock with my regex pattern. Here's what I'm trying to do:

I have HTML text that contains nested  elements, and I want to extract the content of the innermost  tags. However, I can't seem to get my regex pattern right. Here's the code I'm using:

```
import re

html_text = """
<div>
    <div>
        <div>
            Innermost Content 1
        </div>
    </div>
    <div>
        Innermost Content 2
    </div>
</div>
"""

pattern = r'<div>(.*?)<\/div>'
result = re.findall(pattern, html_text, re.DOTALL)

print(result)
```

I expected this code to return the content of the innermost  elements, like this:

```
['Innermost Content 1', 'Innermost Content 2']
```

But it's not working as expected. What am I doing wrong with my regex pattern, and how can I fix it to achieve the desired result? Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: From the moment the HTML starts getting more complicated (unnecessary spaces, attributes, comments, javascript code...), [this can become very tricky](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags). I'd recommend using a proper HTML parsing library.

Comment: Why don't you just use the built-in HTMLParser?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this modified code with changed pattern and an extra line to get rid of the \n

```
import re

html_text = """
<div>
    <div>
        <div>
            Innermost Content 1
        </div>
    </div>
    <div>
        Innermost Content 2
    </div>
</div>
"""

pattern = r'<div>([^<]*?)<\/div>'
result = re.findall(pattern, html_text, re.DOTALL)

result = [content.strip() for content in result if content.strip()]

print(result)
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use this:

```
[re.sub(r'<div>|<\/div>|\s+', '', item) for item in result]
```

also you can use a proper HTML parsing library like BeautifulSoup instead:

```
# Parse the HTML with BeautifulSoup
soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'html.parser')

# Find all <div> elements and extract their text
div_elements = soup.find_all('div')
for div in div_elements:
    print(div.get_text())
```

Answer (score 0):

One can use re.split()

```
print([st.strip() for st in re.split(r'<div>\n?|<.div>\n?|\n', html_text) if not st.isspace() and st])

['Innermost Content 1', 'Innermost Content 2']
```